# easy install can not install library package

Tags: python, easy-install

I used `easy_install`to install `pydelicious` library but it report an error:

```
>easy_install pydelicious-0.6-py2.6.egg
Searching for pydelicious-0.6-py2.6.egg
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pydelicious-0.6-py2.6.egg/
Couldn't find index page for 'pydelicious-0.6-py2.6.egg' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pydelicious-0.6-py2.6.egg
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pydelicious-0.6-py2.6.egg')
```

I have already downloaded the library but the command still does not work. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you try to install it like so: `easy_install pydelicious` ?

Comment: @user1238367 error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pydelicious')

Comment: If there's no other error then it's not compatible with your Python version most likely. Download it from the developer's website and install it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `easy_install -f /path/to/pydelicious-0.6-py2.6.egg`?

Comment: I am trying.....Do you know how to handle it when the path has whitespace?

Comment: Add quotes: `easy_install -f "/path/to/pydelicious-0.6-py2.6.egg"`

Answer (score 0):

I think easy_install search in internet your pack. You must unzip and use setup.py in downloaded file

Comment: But from the error report, it shows the local disk was searched

Comment: hmm my mistake. you true